# Pandas - getting difference between values of same user in a for loop

Tags: pandas

I'm trying to get the difference of values between different weeks of an intervention for the same user. I put my code below, which is a mock user set with different values of different weeks. My attempt was to try and loop through each user and subtract the week's values from one another (weeks is called "sequence"), and then append the values in a list.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'sequence': {0: 1.0,
  1: 2.0,
  2: 3.0,
  3: 1.0,
  4: '',
  5: 2.0,
  6: 1.0,
  7: 2.0,
  8: 3.0},
 'value': {0: '4',
  1: '2',
  2: '4',
  3: '4',
  4: '2',
  5: '2',
  6: '4',
  7: '2',
  8: '4'},
 'user': {0: 'user122',
  1: 'user122',
  2: 'user122',
  3: 'user124',
  4: 'user125',
  5: 'user125',
  6: 'user126',
  7: 'user126',
  8: 'user126'}})



lis = []
for usern in set (df['user']):
  week_2 = df[(df['sequence'] == 2) & (df['user'] == usern)]['value'].item()
  week_3 = df[(df['sequence'] == 3) & (df['user'] == usern)]['value'].item()
  

  lis.append(week_3 - week_2)
```

The error I get is that one of the rows is an empty series and that conflicts with the .item() method. One possibility is to use an if-else command looking for a numeric value, but I figured I might not be approach things well, so I'm open to different strategies. The value for user122 should be 2 and the value for user125 should NA, because there's a null value.

In my actual dataset this gets complicated with more columns and values, and I'd prefer to have a solution in a for-loop.

Thank you!

Comment: Note that your `value` is string type. You would need to convert to numeric. Also, there seem to be missing `sequence`, how do you expect to deal with those?

Comment: yeah, that's part of the problem. My approach doesn't work for empty values. seeking input ;)